# Does iOS and android support Indoor positioning system for PWA?

Tags: geolocation, progressive-web-apps, accelerometer, gyroscope, magnetometer

Does iOS and android  support Indoor positioning system for PWA? is it possible to get the Geolocation using wi-fi/ bluetooth for PWA? also is it possible to get the general sensor API (Accelerometre, Gyroscope, Magnetometer)? this question realte to multistorey building.

Comment: Only in some browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Magnetometer  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Accelerometer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gyroscope

Comment: Apple generally about 5 years or more behind on many APis. But many are supported. Bluetooth, USB and several others are a no go on iOS. Many others are good to go.
Visit https://whatwebcando.today/ to see what can be done on your devices. It is a good starting place. https://caniuse.com is the next place to look things up.

Comment: thanks Chris, visted the whatwebcando and get very informative information but there is no information how the device get the geolocation through wi-fi, bluetooth for PWA. i am very clear about GPS but in IPS how it will work on android